# Error Oracle ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

currently Im stuck to solve this issue of error in Oracle. I have a 3 sets of selecting data,

let say:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE3
```

Actually there is no problem for selecting each other table, even when I try to execute to select union all from table2 and table 3, the result is appear, but when it tries to involve to select union all from table1, table2, and table 3, the error is appear and the information listed is:

```
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: xxxxxx
Session ID: xxx Serial number: xxxxxx
```

any help  is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: This appears to be a general communication error (q.v. [here](http://dba-oracle.com/m_ora_03113_end_of_file_on_communications_channel.htm)).  Can you do just the `UNION` between tables 1 and 2, do you also get the error there?

Comment: Ask Oracle support. In general the issue can be ansi syntax, analytic functions + old Oracle versions. It is enough to catch error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  thanks for the response. Yap, I've tried and it returns error both table1 with table2 and table1 with table3, but return a table result when table2 with table3.

Comment: Does the selects take very long time? You could be reaching a time-out.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. hy. thanks for the response. is it the support that you refer to?  https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/MosIndex.jspx?_afrLoop=438928018715621&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=8isjucyrq_4  ? Thank you

Comment: the time for the execution for each table only takes less than 2 Seconds. both of with union or without union @J.Chomel

Comment: Yes it is. I think it is definitely a bug.

Comment: well, it's worth to try, :) @EvgeniyK.

Comment: One tip. Look at alert.log. May be it has some strange and unusual message.

Comment: ah yaaa @EvgeniyK. I forgot to share, I've explore some suggestion out there and the suggestion is by checking the alert.log. after exploring, I found it says that : **Directory does not exist for read/write [D:\app\gifttra.pr\product\11.1.0\client_1\log] [D:\app\gifttra.pr\product\11.1.0\client_1\log\diag] –** after checking it, I add those directory and error still appear

Comment: Then my recommendation it the same: oracle support. Or you give us simple testcase(ddl and test data) which can be reproduced.

Comment: I'd guess you need to check the alert log again, now that you have fixed the alert log directory location issue. ORA-03113 just means the session crashed. I would also look at the table columns to make sure the datatypes match up, and try excluding any BLOB, XMLTYPE or other exotic datatypes.